# Creating a data set with imageDatastore

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to create a dataset of my own like CIFAR-10 but not with RGB values but CEDD feature vector of image. I am creating a imageDatastore and reading the images and thier labels with following code :

```
imageFolder = fullfile('G:\9th Semester\Project - 2\myDataset');
imds = imageDatastore(imageFolder,'LabelSource', 'foldernames', 'IncludeSubfolders',true);
[trainingSet , testingSet] = splitEachLabel(imds , 0.8 , 'randomize');
trainingSet = shuffle(trainingSet);
testingSet = shuffle(testingSet);
data = [];
labels = char.empty(0,10);
cedd = [];
for i=1:size(trainingSet.Files)
    image = readimage(trainingSet,i);
    cedd = CEDD(image);
    zerosCount = 0 ;
    for j=1:144
        if cedd(j) == 0
            zerosCount=zerosCount + 1;
        end
    end
    if zerosCount ~= 144
        data(i , :) = cedd;
        labels(i ,: ) = trainingSet.Labels(i);
    end
end
save('train.mat' , 'data' , 'labels');
```

But is giving me this error :

> Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-10 and the size of the right side is 1-by-3.
>   Error in dataset (line 20)
>           labels(i ,: ) = trainingSet.Labels(i);

Any help will be much appreciated !

Comment: On line twenty you have `trainginSet.Labels(i)` which has 3 elements, and you are trying to put it into `labels(i,:)` which has 10 elements. Since the number of elements in the target and source are different, Matlab can't perform the assignment.

Comment: @David so whats the solution ? i have varying size on right hand side . How i can achieve this !

Comment: You can try using `labels` as cell array: `labels = cell(10,1);`... `labels{i} = trainingSet.Labels(i);`.

Comment: @Rotem no i have worked with now string arrays and it is working fine !